# Describing RE's in English Language

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following question from a past exam paper:
[image]

I am struggling to formalise their definitions within the necessary 15 word limit. So far I have:

i) The empty string or set of strings that contain zero or many a's OR b's OR both

ii) The set of strings that start with one or many a's, unless preceded by b's, followed by one or many a's with zero or many possible preceding b's.

My definitions seem rather cumbersome...I just don;t want to lose any info by oversimplifying the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simplify the regular expressions before describing them.

`i` is equivalent to `(a | b)*` which means `any number of a's and b's in any order`.

`ii` is equivalent to `(a|b)*a(a|b)*a` which is hard to describe in only 15 words, my best attempt is `a's and b's in any order, at least two a's, the final letter is a`

Comment: Thanks, I don't get (ii) though. Why only two more b's than a? What if b isn't chosen at all?

Comment: @user559142 Sorry, what I mean is that there are two or more a's, I'm not saying anything specific about how many b's there are.  There can be any number of b's, including none.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tool that attempts to do this for arbitrary regular expressions.  You can find it [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/regex/default.htm).  Enter your regular expression and change the mode to "Explain."

Comment: A nice tool, but the OP isn't struggling with the explanation, but rather with the 15-word constraint of said explanation. Something your tool doesn't help with.

Comment: Surely homework questions should leave something as an exercise to the practitioner? =)  I opine that my tool is useful for fully understanding the regex; summarizing it in your own words would prove comprehension.

Comment: My point is that the OP already has an explanation, s/he merely wanted to fit the explanation in 15 words (or less). In short: while your tool is nice, it isn't an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, it is not a complete answer. It is a partial answer that might lead a clever person to a complete answer. The homework tag description implies that complete answers should not be expected: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info.  I could give an explicit answer, but the asker would gain more if they find the  answer themselves. I argue that, for homework, it is more helpful to give tools and assistance than outright answers. Besides, summarization of known information is not a programming question. ;)